# Problema com mapa no IE?

Tags: php, html, wordpress

Galera seguinte, peguei um modelo na net de um 'mapa do brasil' para linka com outros sites do brasil, porem ele funciona perfeitamente em outros navegadores, o unico problema é o IE que não funciona corretamente, e como não sei como funciona muito bem existe alguma maneira de fazer funcionar no IE ? ( tem muito usuario do site usando IE )
Link da page : http://apcefsp-homolog.adttemp.com.br/outras-apcefs

aqui está o code:

```
<div class="container">

    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-12">
            <h2 class="page-caption"><?= the_title(); ?></h2>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="row">

        <!-- Main Content -->
        <div class="col-md-9 border-right">

        <div class="main-content" id="main">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-12">
                    <div class="text-content">
                        <?php the_content(); ?>
                    </div>

                    <div class="svg-map-div">
                        <div class="svg-container">

                            <svg version="1.1" id="svg-map" viewBox="0 0 450 460" enable-background="new 0 0 450 460" xml:space="preserve">

                                <g>

                                    <a xlink:href="http://www.apcefto.org.br/" xlink:title="APCEF/TO" target="_blank">
                                        <path class="svg-aov" stroke="#FFFFFF" stroke-width="1.0404" stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round" d="M 289.558,235.641
                                        c 16.104,0.575,44.973-31.647,44.835-45.259
                                        c-0.136-13.612-17.227-58.446-22.349-66.088
                                        c-5.122-7.628-37.905,2.506-37.905,2.506
                                        S234.852,233.695,289.558,235.641z"></path>
                                    </a>

                                    <a xlink:href="http://www.apcefba.org.br/" xlink:title="APCEF/BA" target="_blank">
                                        <path class="svg-aov" stroke="#FFFFFF" stroke-width="1.0404" stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round" d="M313.276,197.775
                                        c2.084-2.739,3.506-7.012,6.464-8.764c1.641-0.973,3.232-4.684,4.271-5.163c2.304-1.014,12.161-25.143,20.706-22.513
                                        c1.095,0.342,29.881,3.478,32.153,7.532c2.246-0.506,17.582-8.804,25.829-4.999c9.172,4.246,11.225,20.679,11.2,20.843
                                        c0.107,0.328-0.823,5.765-0.985,5.929c-1.15,1-5.258-0.807-4.22,2.138c1.317,3.751,5.094,10.583,9.97,6.613
                                        c-3.669,6.574-6.846,16.022-13.966,17.747c-5.808,1.411-4.605,13.421-5.178,18.037c-0.465,3.75,0.192,8.448,1.014,12.117
                                        c1.148,4.959-0.821,8.6-1.808,13.42c-0.822,4.162-0.219,8.299-0.987,12.297c-0.271,1.286-4.407,5.723-5.559,7.148
                                        c-1.616-1.426-63.952-37.248-73.1-36.265c1.149-3.738,2.438-9.559-0.741-12.723c-8.625-8.572-0.135-19.335-0.162-19.432
                                        c-0.546-1.725-5.396-6.079-0.026-7.175c-3.175,0.959-1.944-4.027,0.875-3.012C316.726,200.733,314.044,200.527,313.276,197.775z"></path>
                                    </a>

                                    <a xlink:href="http://www.apcefse.org.br/" xlink:title="APCEF/SE" target="_blank">
                                        <path class="svg-aov" stroke="#FFFFFF" stroke-width="1.0404" stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round" d="M408.561,191.735
                                        c0.521-1.505,2.465-0.725,3.533-0.794c2.273-0.164,0.494-2.738,1.095-3.778c2.026-3.793-2.738-5.999-1.998-10.408
                                        c4.024,1.931,9.448,3.397,12.408,6.89c1.343,1.533,5.504,2.656,5.832,4.847c-6.822,0.384-6.901,8.819-11.942,11.572
                                        C413.545,202.212,407.055,193.721,408.561,191.735z"></path>
                                    </a>

                                    <a xlink:href="http://www.apcefpe.org.br/" xlink:title="APCEF/PE" target="_blank">
                                        <path class="svg-aov" stroke="#FFFFFF" stroke-width="1.0404" stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round" d="M373.011,167.238
                                        c2.709-0.795,6.218-14.106,8.325-15.106c4.136-1.986,17.255-1.437,17.8,4.903c-0.437-0.068,8.189-2.273,7.479-1.466
                                        c1.7-0.711,10.518-4.723,12.599-4.82c0.274-0.013,4.603,0.905,3.068,2.315c-0.464,0.439,4.219,3.698,10.789,3.45
                                        c4.66-0.176,5.179-3.436,8.627-4.409c5.89-1.67,4.737,3.698,5.589,6.943c-1.182,2.684-1.646,5.586-2.74,8.285
                                        c-1.533,3.792-9.804,9.791-13.39,12.119c-7.287,4.778-21.802-4.067-22.762-5.67c-0.602-0.985-2.55-5.121-3.178-5.107
                                        c-0.629,0.356-1.04,0.861-1.287,1.519c-0.904-0.013-7.256-3.533-7.502-4.655c-4.769-1.151-5.425,6.108-8.957,6.19
                                        c0.219,0.108-8.244,6.681-7.506,3.314C383.556,170.4,374.241,168.566,373.011,167.238z"></path>
                                    </a>

                                    <a xlink:href="http://www.apcefal.org.br/" xlink:title="APCEF/AL" target="_blank">
                                        <path class="svg-aov" stroke="#FFFFFF" stroke-width="1.0404" stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round" d="M413.953,169.018
                                        c3.78,3.313,9.424,5.505,12.547,5.491c3.229-0.013,5.009-3.328,7.421-4.794c1.177-0.712,10.297-1.93,9.174,1.042
                                        c-1.807,4.848-7.122,8.585-10.024,12.789c-2.792,2-3.423,7.093-6.354,1.864c-3.259,0.424-3.722-4.424-6.957-4.477
                                        c-3.668-2.261-7.998-3.769-11.201-6.342C410.615,172.646,412.751,171.359,413.953,169.018z"></path>
                                    </a>

                                    <a xlink:href="http://www.apcefrn.org.br/" xlink:title="APCEF/RN" target="_blank">
                                        <path class="svg-aov" stroke="#FFFFFF" stroke-width="1.0404" stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round" d="M404.698,138.795
                                        c2.383-4.027,6.574-6.123,8.49-11.149c1.973-5.107,3.834-5.818,8.764-4.642c5.041,1.207,9.339,0.837,14.57,1.671
                                        c7.534,1.193,6.848,10.968,9.206,16.516c-1.919,1.096-13.972,0.521-15.064-1.657c-1.041-2.067-2.904,7.107-5.094,7.3
                                        c1.532-5.847-12.654,1.78-5.424-8.683c2.545-3.67-6.302-0.808-6.711,0.725C410.121,144.013,407.217,139.151,404.698,138.795z"></path>
                                    </a>

                                    <a xlink:href="http://www.apcefce.org.br/" xlink:title="APCEF/CE" target="_blank">
                                        <path class="svg-aov" stroke="#FFFFFF" stroke-width="1.0404" stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round" d="M372.379,104.409
                                        c0.437-1.368,2.961-3.627,1.043-5.025c12.106-1.328,17.581-0.849,27.66,6.723c4.026,3.054,6.822,5.574,10.571,9.147
                                        c1.317,1.273,7.614,4.313,7.914,6.164c-0.054-0.316-5.396,3.696-5.997,5.217c-1.066,2.684-2.659,6.093-4.3,8.298
                                        c0.025-0.055-6.903,3.957-3.532,4.217c-4.41,3.821-1.015,8.135-0.797,11.517c0.196,2.767-4.38,7.587-6.765,5.422
                                        c-2.244-1.999-3.998-5.711-7.779-5.094c-1.998,0.329-5.476,2.189-7.612,0.479c-2.52-2.054,3.669-5.162-0.545-7.354
                                        c-6.987-3.615-1.264-15.393-6.684-20.239c-3.504-3.136,1.753-7.313,0.109-10.749C374.952,111.68,373.694,105.244,372.379,104.409
                                        C373.035,102.314,374.815,105.971,372.379,104.409z"></path>
                                    </a>

                                    <a xlink:href="http://www.apcefpi.org.br/" xlink:title="APCEF/PI" target="_blank">
                                        <path class="svg-aov" stroke="#FFFFFF" stroke-width="1.0404" stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round" d="M320.781,185.478
                                        c2.465-5.149-7.505-20.801-7.505-20.801s47.354-65.868,54.285-66.841c0.299-0.042,6.243,1.768,6.463,2.219
                                        c0.438,0.863-0.821,5.244-0.685,6.587c0.275,2.629,2.879,6.587,2.328,8.684c-1.15,4.736-1.863,6.134,1.369,9.901
                                        c2.794,3.245,0.325,10.16,2.544,14.269c-1.778,4.23,4.768,3.656,3.943,7.613c-0.655,3.163-5.424,7.655-1.176,10.312
                                        c0.274,4.642-4.685,4.983-6.79,7.818c-2.631,2.835-5.535,5.013-7.999,7.888c-0.55,0.671-8.821,4.096-9.998,4.082
                                        c0.302-0.301-17.665-6.449-11.967,2.354c2.463,3.808-1.505,5.56-3.177,8.778c-0.633,2.164-5.836,0.958-7.836,3.205
                                        C328.176,198.748,327.409,180.727,320.781,185.478z"></path>
                                    </a>

                                    <a xlink:href="http://www.apcefma.org.br/" xlink:title="APCEF/MA" target="_blank">
                                        <path class="svg-aov" stroke="#FFFFFF" stroke-width="1.0404" stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round" d="M288.845,127.827
                                        c4.108-2.726,31.195-48.985,31.386-50.395c1.235,0.397,6.084,7.435,7.562,5.025c0.493,0.013-0.328,2.15-0.547,2.396
                                        c-0.054-0.135,2.189-2.286,2.52-2.436c0.521-0.233,1.948,1.903,3.451-0.726c5.642,1.575,1.314,14.31,9.121,11.694
                                        c-1.147,0.384,1.452,0.74,0.848,1.905c5.095-6.587,8.488-0.027,15.337,1.491c2.025,0.466,6.243,0.575,8.162,0.207
                                        c3.808-0.823-2.082,6.847-2.082,6.887c-1.369,2.986-5.041,1.713-6.818,5.683c-0.684,1.549-3.506,4.327-3.042,6.148
                                        c0.494,1.781,2.081,2.863,0.274,4.629c0.603,2.793,3.066,7.109-0.385,9.12c-4.601,4.383,2.304,7.52,1.316,11.598
                                        c-0.9,3.726-6.244,5.725-9.147,2.78c-4.847-0.11-6.872,3.821-10.406,6.45c-2.74,2.041-8.793,2.493-10.327,5.642
                                        c-1.918,3.929-3.699,8.763-5.341,12.79c-1.699,4.204,6.383,18.762-4.328,15.611c-0.932-0.273-3.396-4.725-3.396-5.738
                                        c-0.081-3.739-2.738-4.176-4.821-7.477c0.356-3.025,2.466-6.929,4.766-8.052c3.342-1.63,1.919-6.629-2.466-4.465
                                        c-3.505,1.726-4.709-2.794-6.958-5.287c0.548,0.59-3.064-4.696-3.146-3.697c0.19-1.89,2.876-5.833,3.341-8.448
                                        c0.575-3.259,0.52-6.764-0.521-10.105c-0.63-2.068-4.656-4.521-6.518-4.437c-1.289,0.287-2.443,0-3.427-0.878
                                        C290.983,125.675,290.983,128.044,288.845,127.827z"></path>
                                    </a>

                                    <a xlink:href="http://www.apcefap.org.br/" xlink:title="APCEF/AP" target="_blank">
                                        <path class="svg-aov" stroke="#FFFFFF" stroke-width="1.0404" stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round" d="M225.198,39.089
                                        c3.274,1.165,3.985-1.315,6.572-1.74c3.616-0.603,5.683,2.725,9.037,2.067c4.055-0.78,7.093-8.025,7.314-11.598
                                        c4.492-3.534,5.503-11.258,9.42-14.68c6.055,4.258,6.11,15.788,7.589,22.485c-0.164,0.083,6.57,7.998,7.944,8.682
                                        c3.396,1.657,3.366,6.203,0.078,9.34c-3.777,3.587-7.449,34.275-7.449,34.275h-46.489c0,0,0.932-50.366,0-51.449
                                        C221.814,36.458,223.334,38.417,225.198,39.089z"></path>
                                    </a>

                                    <a xlink:href="http://www.apcefpa.org.br/" xlink:title="APCEF/PA" target="_blank">
                                        <path class="svg-aov" stroke="#FFFFFF" stroke-width="1.0404" stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round" d="M173.378,50.619
                                        c2.259,2.63,5.629-4.478,7.901-3.82c3.19,0.918,1.478-1.108,5.026-1.752c1.931,0.806,3.096,0.273,3.519-1.631
                                        c0.535-1.26,1.453-1.726,2.725-1.384c1.768-1.684,13.558,3.603,14.68,0.384c0.629-1.821-4.287-5.709-0.302-6.997
                                        c1.643-0.533,6.012,0.808,8.75-0.068c3.986-1.288,4.876,2.684,4.382,6.066c0.631,3.587,13.145,5.766,12.982,7.97
                                        c3.589-1.518,5.354,12.763,7.105,14.447c0.357,4.26,6.304,8.585,7.07,12.544c0.628,3.396,7.065,3.616,8.213,0.095
                                        c2.578-8.133,9.696-10.022,13.475-16.651c4.603-8.038,3.725,3.752,8.955,1.067c2.11,0.411,2.876,3.629,4.574,4.724
                                        c3.18,2.027,7.779,0.974,10.572,3.013c-4.192,4.382,8.188,3.752,9.231,3.875c4.682,0.575,8.104,2.383,11.855,3.629
                                        c-0.164-0.069,4.792,0.52,5.178,1.245c2.026,3.767-4.904,19.214-6.382,21.486c-1.121,1.713-2.932,4.985-3.727,6.834
                                        c-0.902,2.026-4.764,7.313-4.655,9.229c-1.888,0.972-2.248,4.835-5.012,4.328c-3.096,3.026-8.187,4.999-10.27,8.956

                                        C319.302,76.912,319.74,78.76,319.139,77.664z"></path>
                                    </a>

                                    <a xlink:href="http://www.apcefrr.org.br/" xlink:title="APCEF/RR" target="_blank">
                                        <path class="svg-aov" stroke="#FFFFFF" stroke-width="1.0404" stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round" d="M113.18,24.107
                                        1.356,11.53c1.041,4.889,3.231,8.695,6.134,12.16
                                        c1.712,2.027,5.614,2.261,5.724,4.369c0.164,2.945,1.165,6.177,0.329,9.092c-1.547,5.424-36.618,30.471-36.618,30.471
                                        s-12.517-52.736-20.335-54.063C115.261,36.417,111.523,25.682,113.18,24.107z"></path>
                                    </a>

                                    <a xlink:href="http://www.apcefam.org.br/" xlink:title="APCEF/AM" target="_blank">
                                        <path class="svg-aov" stroke="#FFFFFF" stroke-width="1.0404" stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round" d="M10.078,136.412

                                   079-10.625-51.652-8.105c-1.453,1.013-53.626,10.503-55.9,10.819c-6.369,0.875-18.09-7.272-23.719-10.136
                                        c-8.601-4.381-16.61-8.981-26.088-11.05c-10.282-2.259-20.635-4.793-29.878-10.011C4.121,145.766,12.433,144.779,10.078,136.412z"></path>
                                    </a>

                                    <a xlink:href="http://www.apcefac.org.br/" xlink:title="APCEF/AC" target="_blank">
                                        <path class="svg-aov" stroke="#FFFFFF" stroke-width="1.0404" stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round" d="M3.656,148.545
                                        c12.557,7.544,27.524,8.367,41.082,13.2c112.64,0.603c0.313-3.642-0.385-7.299-0.165-10.941c0.096-1.439,1.998-6.533,1.245-7.451
                                        c-6.82,3.149-8.339,7.19-16.733,7.013c-2.136-0.042-2.562-2.492-3.081-4.001c-1.247-3.572-7.218-3.422-10.559-3.778
                                        c6.299-3.41-3.107-11.9-5.216-15.679c-0.52-0.918-3.588-4.655-3.629-5.957C1.642,150.174,6.612,151.968,3.656,148.545z"></path>
                                    </a>

                                    <a xlink:href="http://www.apcefro.org.br/" xlink:title="APCEF/RO" target="_blank">
                                        <path class="svg-aov" stroke="#FFFFFF" stroke-width="1.0404" stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round" d="M83.34,180.232
                                        3.93c-4.041-3.876-8.983-2.645-14.475-3.808c-1.835-0.083-6.053-6.779-7.874-5.327
                                        c-1.821-0.438-5.381-9.094-3.397-11.204c0.124-1.67-0.26-3.204-1.163-4.627c-0.986-2.644,1.041-5.026,0.863-7.806
                                        c-0.384-6.081-1.028-1.986-3.382-1.903C94.336,180.686,85.957,181.671,83.34,180.232z"></path>
                                    </a>

                                    <a xlink:href="http://www.apcefmt.org.br/" xlink:title="APCEF/MT" target="_blank">
                                        <path class="svg-aov" stroke="#FFFFFF" stroke-width="1.0404" stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round" d="M142.237,173.962
                                        c4-0.316-1.888-6.452,5-5.738c7.914,0.808,16.295,0.328,24.279,0.218c1.629-0.013,8.902,1.288,7.395-1.833
                                        c-1.192-2.453,1.821-6.425,0.425-9.725c2.027-0.864,1.289-3.807,2.629-5.107c1
                                        C143.581,176.618,141.937,174.714,142.237,173.962z"></path>
                                    </a>

                                    <a xlink:href="http://www.apcefms.org.br/" xlink:title="APCEF/MS" target="_blank">
                                        <path class="svg-aov" stroke="#FFFFFF" stroke-width="1.0404" stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round" d="M183.198,294.536
                                        c2.136-4.464,3.177-9.394,5.312-13.61c1.712-3.344-4.067-7.587-2.423-9.807c0.027-0.026,2.738,3.641,3.917,3.725
                                     2.409c-2.013-4.354-0.111-14.625-4.849-17.088c-1.206-0.659-7.092-2.36-7.504-1.945
                                        c-1.699,1.777-3.739,1.562-6.121,1.121c-2.904,0.027-5.629-1.614-8.243-1.203c-4.178,0.656-0.603-2.986-1.645-3.535
                                        c0.932-2.847,1.411-9.912,0.453-11.856c-0.165-0.331-3.52-7.232-2.547-8.108C186.306,297.688,182.334,299.415,183.198,294.536z"></path>
                                    </a>

                                    <a xlink:href="http://www.apcefgo.org.br/" xlink:title="APCEF/GO" target="_blank">
                                        <path class="svg-aov" stroke="#FFFFFF" stroke-width="1.0404" stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round" d="M237.768,270.519
                                        c0.628-2.904,1.835-7.396,4.709-8.766c1.015-1.644,1.754-5.147,2.275-5.586c9-0.931,0.326-1.408,1.037-1.438
                                        c0.108,0.534,0.274,1.013,0.602,1.452c-0.602-0.261,9.697-0.095,8.82,1.534c0.36-0.657-0.602-3.11,0.221-3.438
                                        c1.039-0.411,3.971,1.368,6.351,0.438c1.045-0.397,7.889-2.807,7.671-3.683c0.767,0.905,1.262,2.67,2.85,1.286
                                        c-2.632,2.274-2.576,4.466,1.258,3.821c-1.861,1.438-2.846,4.341-2.382,6.547c0.357,1.643,3.752,5.973,3.478,6.751

                                        c-3.724-0.604,1.04-3.231,0.22-4.109c-1.89-1.916-4.382,1.756-3.588-3.012C239.602,274.627,237.055,273.038,237.768,270.519z"></path>
                                    </a>

                                    <a xlink:href="http://www.apcefpr.org.br/" xlink:title="APCEF/PR" target="_blank">
                                        <path class="svg-aov" stroke="#FFFFFF" stroke-width="1.0404" stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round" d="M222.225,363.694
                              28,2.19-5.754,8.929-8.41,8.984c-4.054,0.057-14.215,14.68-14.215,14.68s-37.329-12.05-40.287-11.285
                                        c-3.875-1.449-2.698-6.491-6.054-8.216C226.663,364.623,222.498,367.8,222.225,363.694z"></path>
                                    </a>

                                    <a xlink:href="http://www.apcefsc.org.br/" xlink:title="APCEF/SC" target="_blank">
                                        <path class="svg-aov" stroke="#FFFFFF" stroke-width="1.0404" stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round" d="M231.029,383.959
                                        c1.669-3.338-0.284-10.516,4.573-10.569c6.631-0.109,13.639,3.559,20.402,3.888c1.317,0.055,5.231,2.163,4.357-1.15
                                        c-1.095-4.164,3.945-1.863,5.67-3.179c2.274-1.724,8.187-4.106,11.311-1.367c1.423,1.809,20.05-5.395,13.284,3.946
                                        c-1.368,1.395,0.713,10.789,0.466,10.734c-3.449,4.438,1.726,11.666-5.096,15.334c-2.901,1.536-7.284,7.779-9.64,9.995
                                        C276.085,411.866,233.534,382.918,231.029,383.959z"></path>
                                    </a>

                                    <a xlink:href="http://www.apcefrs.org.br/" xlink:title="APCEF/RS" target="_blank">
                                        <path class="svg-aov" stroke="#FFFFFF" stroke-width="1.0404" stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round" d="M191.236,416.881

                                        c-3.696,7.614-8.872,12.765-15.886,17.42c-7.394,4.902-7.339,11.941-13.257,17.693c-8.091,7.942-10.159-0.574-4.08-5.752
                                        c3.806-3.231-22.527-19.746-25.578-22.732c-1.918-1.862-2.384,0.274-4.219,1.15c-2.547,1.205-1.917-2.822-3.588-4.273
                                        c-2.3-1.999-4.793-5.479-7.737-6.68c-3.478-1.367-5.615,5.145-9.052,0.821C189.168,418.854,190.332,418.032,191.236,416.881z"></path>
                                    </a>

                                    <a xlink:href="http://www.apcefsp.org.br/" xlink:title="APCEF/SP" target="_blank">
                                        <path class="svg-aov" stroke="#FFFFFF" stroke-width="1.0404" stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round" d="M239.3,330.554

                                        c-4.271-2.244-6.958,2.96-9.258,1.918c-4.271-1.918-16.98,13.092-19.638,15.336c0.245-0.218-1.148-1.479-1.587-2.685
                                        c-0.466-1.369-2.658,0.385-4.025,0.082c-0.986-0.192,1.751-4.079-2.303-4.52c-1.369-0.164-3.753,0.303-4.929,0.084
                                        c-2.903-0.547,0.108-2.41-0.439-3.862c-1.067-2.986-3.013-4.931-3.751-7.779c-0.52-1.945,0.165-7.531-3.615-7.395
                                        c-0.848-2.956-6.628-1.451-9.066-1.862c-0.162,0.163-8.846-2.684-10.079-2.684c-1.616-0.029-6.791-3.396-7.121-0.274
                                        C247.982,330.386,239.876,331.21,239.3,330.554z"></path>
                                    </a>

                                    <a xlink:href="http://www.apcefmg.org.br/" xlink:title="APCEF/MG" target="_blank">
                                        <path class="svg-aov" stroke="#FFFFFF" stroke-width="1.0404" stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round" d="M262.881,297.305
                                  0.536,5.53,3.284,8.106,3.886c2.301,3.578,7.503,0.537,10.298,3.001c1.755,1.589,2.188,3.397,3.396,5.313
                                        c1.314,2.052,3.86-0.465,5.726-0.109c3.257,0.656,6.326,2.026,9.338,3.723c2.19,1.205,0.768,3.179-0.548,4.573
                                        c-0.765,0.796-3.259,6.165-2.627,5.643c-2.138,1.781-2.628-1.669-3.397,2.764c-0.628,3.674,0.164,4.714,3.149,7.015
                                        c4.901,3.229-6.765,3.12-6.71,3.504c0.22,0.601-2.846,41.96-3.835,42.179c-6.737,1.562-14.513,5.311-21.744,7.012
                                9.858,0.631C262.993,300.562,262.336,299.274,262.881,297.305z"></path>
                                    </a>

                                    <a xlink:href="http://www.apcefrj.org.br/" xlink:title="APCEF/RJ" target="_blank">
                                        <path class="svg-aov" stroke="#FFFFFF" stroke-width="1.0404" stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round" d="M332.886,337.429
                                        c-1.26-2.768,8.409-4.795,7.89-6.71c-3.177-1.864-4.602,1.148-6.63-2.959c4.274-0.686,9.533-4.49,13.831-3.562
                                        c0.548-0.219,4.902-1.753,4.96,0.167c2.546-1.566,5.479-2.412,8.105-3.837c2.246-1.206,0.932-8.218,3.725-9.643
                                        c6.054-3.123,1.398,1.836,7.066,2.959c5.888,1.205,5.395,1.48,5.641,7.067c0.247,5.642-8.763,4.381-11.063,8.764
                                        c-1.039,1.999,1.698,5.368-3.368,4.903c-4.188-0.413-10.628,2.355-9.285-3.18c-1.039-0.08-1.861,0.301-2.464,1.124
                                        c0,0,0.105,2.767-0.74,2.741c-0.766-0.056-7.643,1.094-7.449,0.463c1.398-0.359,2.708-0.684,4.135-0.794
                                        c-1.667-0.713-2.957-1.839-4.901-0.142c0.465,0.195-4.227-0.086-3.379-0.113c-0.521,1.727-3.814,0.699-3.879,3.045
                                        C336.717,337.908,333.927,342.41,332.886,337.429z"></path>
                                    </a>

                                    <a xlink:href="http://www.apcefes.org.br/" xlink:title="APCEF/ES" target="_blank">
                                        <path class="svg-aov" stroke="#FFFFFF" stroke-width="1.0404" stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round" d="M367.119,308.834
                                        c1.044-1.999-0.298-5.451,1.841-6.326c3.697-1.453,3.858-0.467,5.941-4.49c0.767-1.563,3.999-5.807,2.848-7.835
                                        c-0.439-0.765-3.204-3.613-3.286-4.05c1.04-0.249,2.079-0.219,3.123,0.054c1.366-0.654-6.465-10.519,2.137-8.054
                                        c-1.204-0.655-1.535-1.365-0.932-2.135c4.358-0.138,13.856,0.027,12.845,6.738c-0.577,3.835,0.933,8.079-0.577,11.804
                                        c-0.218,0.576-5.861,8.954-5.831,8.954c0.985,3.289-5.18,5.808-6.054,8.165c-1.313,3.56-2.135,3.013-5.614,2.573
                                        c-1.64-0.274-3.202-0.768-4.736-1.451C368.819,311.297,369.424,309.055,367.119,308.834z"></path>
                                    </a>

                                    <a xlink:href="http://www.apcefdf.org.br/" xlink:title="APCEF/DF" target="_blank">
                                        <path class="svg-aov" stroke="#FFFFFF" stroke-width="1.0404" stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round" d="M292.461,246.197
                                        c0,0,12.929-2.903,14.188,0c1.233,2.903,0.659,10.683-1.424,11.504c-2.08,0.849-14.296-1.806-14.023-3.313
                                        C291.503,252.853,292.461,246.197,292.461,246.197z"></path>
                                    </a>

                                    <a xlink:href="http://www.apcefpb.org.br/" xlink:title="APCEF/PB" target="_blank">
                                        <path class="svg-aov" stroke="#FFFFFF" stroke-width="1.0404" stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round" d="M401.575,141.096

                                        c-2.626,1.767-6.571,1.917-9.558,2.109c-0.162,1.232-3.943,4.438-5.259,4.916c-3.122,1.149-2.657-2.727-5.095-3.602
                                        c0.713-1.124,4.082-5.203,3.725-6.205c-1.423-3.846-12.051,5.52-14.981,3.506c-1.396-0.973-6.218,1.493-3.476-2.588
                                        C405.574,150.776,400.398,142.889,401.575,141.096z"></path>
                                    </a>

                                </g>
                            </svg>

                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>

    </div>

    <!-- Sidebar -->
    <div class="col-md-3" id="sidebar">
        <?php get_sidebar(); ?>
    </div>
</div>
</div>
```

```
<!-- Error -->
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-12">

            <!-- Main Content -->
            <div class="main-content" id="main">
                <div class="text-content">
                    <p><?php _e( 'Sorry, no posts matched your criteria.' ); ?></p>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Tirei um pouco do codigo de desenho pq nao cabia aqui na postagem

Answer (score 1):

Adicione no seu CSS um `min-height: 613px;` ao `svg`, que é a altura do mapa, e o IE irá ajustar as dimensões:

```
#svg-map{
   min-height: 613px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Bom fiz como o @dvd comentou , mas nao deu certo, mudei um pouco as divs e algumas coisas no CSS e funcionou

vou deixar como abri a div e como deixei o CSS pra vcs ver

```
        <div>
                        <div class="svg-map-centro">
  <svg version="1.1" id="svg-map" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" x="0px" y="0px" width="650px" height="660px" viewBox="0 0 450 460" enable-background="new 0 0 450 460" xml:space="preserve">
    <g>
      <a xlink:href="http://www.apcefto.org.br/" target="_blank" >
        <path stroke="#FFFFFF" stroke-width="1.0404" stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round" d="M289.558,235.641
        c16.104,0.575,44.973-31.647,44.835-45.259c-0.136-13.612-17.227-58.446-22.349-66.088c-5.122-7.628-37.905,2.506-37.905,2.506
        S234.852,233.695,289.558,235.641z"></path>
        <text transform="matrix(1 0 0 1 287.0137 188.3208)" fill="#FFFFFF">TO</text>
      </a>
      <a xlink:href="http://www.apcefba.org.br/ target="_blank">
        <path stroke="#FFFFFF" stroke-width="1.0404" stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round" d="M313.276,197.775
        c2.084-2.739,3.506-7.012,6.464-8.764c1.641-0.973,3.232-4.684,4.271-5.163c2.304-1.014,12.161-25.143,20.706-22.513
        c1.095,0.342,29.881,3.478,32.153,7.532c2.246-0.506,17.582-8.804,25.829-4.999c9.172,4.246,11.225,20.679,11.2,20.843
        c0.107,0.328-0.823,5.765-0.985,5.929c-1.15,1-5.258-0.807-4.22,2.138c1.317,3.751,5.094,10.583,9.97,6.613
        c-3.669,6.574-6.846,16.022-13.966,17.747c-5.808,1.411-4.605,13.421-5.178,18.037c-0.465,3.75,0.192,8.448,1.014,12.117
        c1.148,4.959-0.821,8.6-1.808,13.42c-0.822,4.162-0.219,8.299-0.987,12.297c-0.271,1.286-4.407,5.723-5.559,7.148
        c-1.616-1.426-63.952-37.248-73.1-36.265c1.149-3.738,2.438-9.559-0.741-12.723c-8.625-8.572-0.135-19.335-0.162-19.432
        c-0.546-1.725-5.396-6.079-0.026-7.175c-3.175,0.959-1.944-4.027,0.875-3.012C316.726,200.733,314.044,200.527,313.276,197.775z"></path>
        <text transform="matrix(1 0 0 1 359.7324 210.1221)" fill="#FFFFFF">BA</text>
      </a>
```

E aqui o CSS

```
.svg-map-centro {
    text-align: center;
}
#svg-map path { fill:#c1c1c1 }
    #svg-map { text-align: center;}
    #svg-map text { fill:#fff; font:12px Arial-BoldMT, sans-serif; cursor:pointer }
    #svg-map a{ text-decoration:none }
    #svg-map a:hover { cursor:pointer; text-decoration:none }
    #svg-map a:hover path{ fill:#F36F21 !important }
    #svg-map .circle { fill:#c1c1c1}
    #svg-map a:hover .circle { fill:#F36F21 !important; cursor:pointer }
```